# How to read from specific line to specific line from a large file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, file-io

And add these lines to a ListBox. (Windows Form)

I would use:

```
String file_name = @"x:\....";
int first_line = 24536;
int last_line = 25536;

for ( int i = first_line; i <= last_line; i++)
{
  this.listBox.Items.Add(File.ReadLines(this.file_name).ElementAt(i));
}
```

But this takes a lot of time to load 1000 lines.

How can I do this more efficiently (faster)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you're calling `ElementAt` each time - which means reading the file *from scratch* for each new line.

Try this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(fileName)
                     .Skip(firstLine - 1) // Assuming 1-based line numbers
                     .Take(lastLine - firstLine)
                     .ToArray();
listBox.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

(Note that I've removed the unconventional underscores from your variable names.)

Comment: As a side note: Line numbers are usually 1-index based. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. It's a lot faster than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the File lines in a list and then call it by index id

```
IEnumerable<string> = File.ReadLines(@"c:\test.txt")
                      .Take(NumberOfLines);
```

Comment: but this results in reading the whole file, and using unnecessarily memory.